# Android service stopping unexpectedly

Tags: android, service

I have a service that also contains an activity the problem is sometimes it gets shut down by the operating system.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: don't start it in the first place. Or be more specific / show some code =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "service that contains an activity".

The OS can and will shut down services based on demand for memory. How often this happens depends on what you have running on your device, and the amount of memory that your device has.

To try to minimize this, you can call Service.[startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). Please read the javadocs for the proper usage, and please look at [stopForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopForeground%28boolean%29) as well.

Note that this is still no guarantee. You must author your app to gracefully handle when your service is destroyed. Please read up on the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) lifecycle to understand how to handle this.

Even if you could keep your service running at all times, it would be a bad idea. This is not a personal computer plugged in to AC power. A service that is perpetually running will greatly effect the battery life of the device.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make any sense that you would have a service that *contains* an activity.  You can have a service to which an Activity is *connected*, but not one that holds an Activity.  Services, along with the rest of your app, can be killed off by the Android OS at any time, and will be restored when the user navigates back to them.  Instead you need to design your app in such a way that it is tolerant to these lifecycle events, and doesn't need to be kept around forever.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a service or an activity can not be guaranteed to run all the time. You have to handled the lifecycle events of the service like shutdown and start.